# Lightweight portable cross-platform client-server database

Tags: database, cross-platform, portable-database

Is there a lightweight (in size and memory usage), portable (that i can copy and paste it to another computer without reconfiguration, or rsync it with ease), cross-platform (that runs on windows and linux, at least at data level), client-server (because there would be more than one user write at the same time, so i wont use sqlite or any other embedded database) database?

what are my options?

i don't care if it's sql or nosql, i don't care about the security too..

Answer (score 1):

How about [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/)? It would require a JRE (Java), but other than that, it should do exactly what you want.

Alternatively, you could write a small wrapper for SQLite (or any other embedded database) and just ship that instead. Your wrapper would expose some sort of network-level API of your choosing.

Comment: btw the second idea is a nice idea, since sqlite file is cross-platform.. :3 thanks..

Comment: i think i'll go with H2 database.. *for now, until i found better one*